# Have we now passed beta criteria?

Tags: discussion

We now have 90% questions answered, and 10 users over 2K rep. I think that is the criteria for a beta site to graduate.

Is there anything else we need to do, do we get notified I am not quite sure now?

Comment: The answer ratio must not exclude completely unanswered questions. There are a fair number of questions with 0 answers, but I don't see enough with only 1 answer that would bring it down to a 1.7 average...

Comment: Answered questions are questions with an answer that has been voted, or accepted.

Comment: Ah, now THAT makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The site looks pretty good overall and is well on its way to graduation. There is a recent blog post that lists the post-90-day beta/graduation process.

[**Does this site have a chance of succeeding?**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/does-this-site-have-a-chance-of-succeeding/)

You have past that 90-day *minimum* so it's just a matter of time and building up the content needed to reach that critical mass needed to graduate. Your traffic is looking strong; It's been growing steadily since early June. There are a few sites ahead of you in the queue, so Jin should be able to get started on your site soon after those launch.

**A few areas you can work on** —

**Avid Users**: You barely *squeak by* with (10) +2K rep users and (5) +3K rep users. That means you are not really voting enough on your high-quality content. You can vote 40 times per day. The reputation requirements to administer this site will increase after graduation. [Use your votes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

**90% questions answered** is admirable but it's on the lower end of "excellent." I think this site can do better. A concerted effort to get those hardest-to-answer questions answered should help. If the question isn't worth answering ("unanswerable" as asked, or low quality), a bit of a cleanup effort might be helpful. That's best initiated and organized through a meta post. Go for it.

Comment: The number of 2K users depends from their participation to the site; if a user aswers a question every 5 days, there is few voters can do. The problem of having less votes than answers should get is a problem for all users; if a user participates few has less chances to get voted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what is required, but things to notice.

- We are looking very good in questions / day and visits / day. When you sort by traffic on stackexchange, we list in the middle, of all launched sites, meaning our site do better than about half of all launched sites regarding traffic. Things look about the same for questions per day.

One thing is starts, another thing is how the site actual function. I can image things like the community behind the site also matters. Right now we have a few very active users with a lot of rep, how would the site handle do if they were to stop contributing.

Also I would think that these stats are more guidelines, and that real persons review a site looking at more than these stats.

One thing that we might consider is moderators. Right now we only have moderators, so maybe it's about site to do an election. This is something I have bought of but put out since it's hollyday season for a lot right now.

I would like to get some official feedback though.

Answer (score 0):

We could have passed the criteria to be over the beta phase, but since we are past the ninety day after which a beta site is evaluated, it has not been evaluated, yet.
As reported from the Area 51 site, "This site will remain in beta indefinitely so it can grow; we will continue to evaluate its site statistics and overall health." I interpret it as meaning that there is not a set moment when a beta site is evaluated, after the ninetieth day.

It could also be that the answer ratio still need to improved, and *Drupal Answers* is not ready for leaving the beta phase.

Consider that, since the moment a site leave the beta phase, the reputation associated with most of the privileges is increased. That means most of the users would not be anymore able to participate to the site; this means, for example, that eight users would not be able to use the moderator tools, thirteen users would not be able to suggest tag synonyms, nine users would not be able to approve tag wikis, and forty-eight user would not be able to vote for closing questions.

Comment: Yeah, it is a shame that reputation doesn't transfer between SE sites, or at least from SO to the sister sites that have spun off.

Comment: Who has a high reputation on SO because of answers about C# doesn't automatically know Drupal; therefore, he should not have an automatic high reputation on DA.

Comment: I mostly agree, but the same thing happens on SO.  I have a decent reputation there, mainly from answers to Drupal and AS3 questions.  The same reputation shows up if I answer a Ruby question, but the only way to see that I am unqualified to answer is to dig into my profile.

Comment: The problem is that is not possible to know when you have answered a question about Drupal. The fact the question is tagged "drupal" doesn't mean the question is strictly about Drupal; It could be a question asking which CMS to use between Drupal and other two CMS's. Even supposing to consider about Drupal any question tagged "drupal," I don't find it right that a user gets, e.g., 70 points in two different SE sites for answering a question on a single SE site. What would happen if a similar question (or the same question) is asked in both SO and DA?

Comment: With what you are suggesting, you would get reputation three times: once because the votes for the answer you give on SO, once because the reputation that is transferred to DA, and once because the votes you get for the answer you give on DA.